# Write a Python program to print the following sequence of numbers (N to be entered by user): X + X^2/2! + X^3/3!+... Upto Nth Term

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, sequence, nested-for-loop

The question has already been mentioned. I have written a code for it, and i am not getting the desired output. We don't have to actually find the sum, only display all the individual addends, and that is the part i am having trouble with.

Here is the code I have written:

```
x = int(input("Please enter the base number: "))
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms: "))
s = 0
factorial = 1
for j in range(1,n+1):
    factorial = factorial*j
    for i in range(x,n+1):
        s = (x**i)/factorial
        print(s,end='+')
```

My output is coming:

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 5
4.0+8.0+16.0+32.0+2.0+4.0+8.0+16.0+0.6666666666666666+1.3333333333333333+2.6666666666666665+5.333333333333333+0.16666666666666666+0.3333333333333333+0.6666666666666666+1.3333333333333333+0.03333333333333333+0.06666666666666667+0.13333333333333333+0.26666666666666666+
```

which is obviously not the answer i am looking for. My desired output would be something like this:

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 5
2.0+2.0+1.33333+0.66667+0.26667+
```

What changes should i make within the code to get the required results?

- Side note: I am working on a Mac with Python version 3.8.5

Comment: At first glance: why are there two loops? `X + X^2/2! + X^3/3!` is `sum(x**i/factorial(i) for i in range(N))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two loops. You only need one loop because your series is generalized to `x**n/factorial(n)` and you only want to increment the value of `n`.

```
x = 2 # int(input("Please enter the base number: "))
n = 5 # int(input("Please enter the number of terms: "))
s = 0
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial = factorial*i
    s = (x**i) / factorial
    print(s, end='+')
```

This prints:

```
2.0+2.0+1.3333333333333333+0.6666666666666666+0.26666666666666666+
```

Of course, if you want to format the numbers to a fixed number of decimal places, specify that using a f-string:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial = factorial*i
    s = (x**i) / factorial
    print(f"{s:.6f}", end='+')
```

```
2.000000+2.000000+1.333333+0.666667+0.266667+
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one loop. And secondly, try to calculate the next term from the previous one, so to keep the calculations from getting really big:

```
value = 1
for j in range(1,n+1):
    value *= x / j
    print(value,end='+')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error is on the line 6 : `factorial = factorial*j`.
What you should do is replace it with `factorial += 1` which will increment factorial by one every time you pass in the loop.

This should be the corrected code :

```
x = int(input("Please enter the base number: "))
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms: "))
s = 0
factorial = 1
for j in range(1,n+1):
    factorial = factorial+1
    for i in range(x,n+1):
        s = (x**i)/factorial
        print(s,end='+')
```

and this is the result :

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 5
2.0+4.0+8.0+16.0+1.3333333333333333+2.6666666666666665+5.333333333333333+10.666666666666666+1.0+2.0+4.0+8.0+0.8+1.6+3.2+6.4+0.6666666666666666+1.3333333333333333+2.6666666666666665+5.333333333333333+
```

Let me know if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Did you compare your result with OP's desired result?